# How do I add style to a html element created with VBA?

Tags: html, css, vba

I create new TD elements as follows

```
Dim TD As HTMLTableCell
Set TD = HTMLdoc.createElement("TD")
Set TR = TRelements.Item(1)
TD.innerHTML = "<span>blabla</span>"
TR.insertAdjacentElement "afterbegin", TD
```

I know how to add styling to the span inside the to be created TD element:

```
<span style=""font-size:9pt"">blabla</span>
```

But how do I add styling (e.g. borders and background color) to the new TD element itself?

Comment: Note that in your example you use `<span style=""font-size:9pt"">blabla</span>` instead of `<span style="font-size:9pt">blabla</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTMLTableCell` object has the following properties:

- align
- background
- bgColor
- borderColor
- borderColorDark
- borderColorLight
- cellIndex
- colSpan
- height
- noWrap
- rowSpan
- vAlign
- width